# How do I create animations with LibGDX using the TextureAtlas?

Tags: java, libgdx

How come I can't load my animation with the TextureAtlas like this? (The path isn't correct, but I don't know how to change that)

`walk_up = new Animation<TextureRegion>(.5f, atlas.findRegions("walk_up") , PlayMode.LOOP);`

This is what [Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM4z6.png) currently looks like.

Comment: Have you initialized `atlas` ?

Comment: And what error(s) do you get

Comment: Show you atlas txt file

Comment: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.knarkzel.game.Player.load(Player.java:62)
 at com.knarkzel.game.Player.<init>(Player.java:26)
 at com.knarkzel.game.Main.create(Main.java:26)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)